# Cinema Booking Program: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, list, validation, int, typeerror

so this is a program I have been writing for my Computing gcse course work, i have on only been learning python for a few months so excuse my incompetence. When you run this you get the error in the title. I understand that its something to do with converting an integer into a list, but i need help quick as this piece is due in today. Thanks in advance.

```
Seats = [] #Each Row has ten seats available atm

print("""
E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 E10
D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 B10
A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 A10""")
# This will help people to understand where they are booking
Data = open('Cinema.csv', 'r+') #Open and reads and allows to be written in  file
line = Data.readlines()
if line!='':
    Seats = [line]
#The proccess above checks whether the .csv file contains anything and if
#it does then it sets the list seats to the values in the file.
else:
    Seats = [10,10,10,10,10]
#sets seats to all empty when there is nothing in there is nothing on thr .csv file
EntryPeople = 0
while True: #loops back to here and askes question angain on line bellow
    try:
        EntryPeople = int(input("How many people do you wish to book for? MAXIMUM 6!"))
    except ValueError:
        print("You cant type that in its got to be an Integer")
    else:
#This section makes sure that what is entered is an integer and pastes that they need
#to enter one if they wish to continue.
        while EntryPeople >6: #Loops back to this point if they enter more than 6
            print("Please Enter a Number bellow six!") #Reminds them
            EntryPeople = int(input("Many people do you wish to book for? MAXIMUM 6!"))
#This part above puts a cap on how man people they can book at once
        else:
            EntryRow = input("Which row would you like to book for?")
            Upper = EntryRow.upper()
            while not Upper in ('A','B','C','D','E'):
                print("That is not a row")
                EntryRow = input("Which row would you like to book for?")
                Upper = EntryRow.upper()
#Checks whether the row is valid
            else:
                Index = ord(EntryRow.upper()) -65
                if Seats[Index]- EntryPeople > -1:
                    Seats[Index] = Seats[Index] - EntryPeople
                    print("Thank you for booking seats on row: " +EntryRow.upper())
                    Data = open('Cinema.csv', 'wt')
                    for item in Seats:
                        Data.write("%s\n" % item)#copies whats in the list to the file
                    Data.close()
#This segmant above forces the input to uppercase because all uppercase have a value. A = 65 if       you
#subtract 65 form 65 you get 0. 0 is the corresponding number to A in the list.
#Therefore B=1; it works for any value entered.
                else:
                    print("i'm Sorry but those seats are currently unavailable")
                    print("Available seats on row A:")
                    print(Seats[0])
                    print("Available seats on row B:")
                    print(Seats[1])
                    print("Available seats on row c:")
                    print(Seats[2])
                    print("Available seats on row D:")
                    print(Seats[3])
                    print("Available seats on row E:")
                    print(Seats[4])#pretty prints free seats
                    Data.close()
                    import sys
                    sys.exit()
 #Copies Booked seats into a file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now what I found is that line 11

```
line = Data.readlines()
```

always returns a list therefore the next if statement (line 12) is alwas executed since a list is always != ' '

```
if line!='':
    Seats = [line]
```

results that Seats is a list of a list and your statement in line 42

```
Seats[Index]
```

returns a list and you can't subtract an int from a list. Hence the TypeError

I guess the following should do the job

```
if line:
    Seats = [int(i) for i in line]
```

Comment: Thanks for help i understand the problem better now but unfortunately i still get the TypeError

Comment: edited the solution slightly. We need to convert the strings we get from the readlines() method to ints and store it in Seats